# Need help on Sonar Jasmine spec failures

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jasmine

I'm getting the following exception when trying to build the sonar dashboard using maven (mvn sonar:sonar)

```
Failed to execute goal com.github.searls:jasmine-maven-plugin:1.2.0.0:test (default) on project sample-web: There were Jasmine spec failures. -> [Help 1]
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project operative-global: Can not execute Sonar: Unable to execute maven plugin: Exception during execution of org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.1:cobertura -> [Help 2]
```

Could someone help me with the suggestions/comments to resolve the problem?

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to compatability issues. The issue gets resolved after upgrading the jars to the latest version.